# How to download the processing.js JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, download, processing.js

I've searched around the web for a step by step guide. From zero for beginners and have not yet found an answer.

In the library page I just see a bunch of code when I click on download processing.js. I don't know what to do with it. How can I download (step by step if possible) a js library? More specifically, processing.js.

Comment: Maybe the procedure for any library would help so any advice on it will be great!

Comment: http://processingjs.org/download/ Just download the `processing.js` file from there and include it in the page in which you need it, in whichever way is necessary based on your platform. In plain HTML, for example, `<script src="/PATH_TO_DIRECTORY/processing.js"></script>` before the custom script you're writing, where `PATH_TO_DIRECTORY` is the location of the file

Comment: Well, I think you need to learn HTML

Comment: Right click and press "save link as". Then include the javascript file in your html as described on the website http://processingjs.org/learning/

Comment: Thank you all! The part of right click and "save link as" was what I was missing.

Comment: Speaking as the caretaker of Processing.js: the current version is always available on https://www.npmjs.com/package/processing-js - Speaking as a SO member: your question and title do not line up, because you're not asking how to download it at all, you're asking for tutorials on using Processing.js, which is really not what SO is for and will get your question closed because it's [off-topic](/help/on-topc)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) is a guide on using Processing.js, which includes directions on how to download the library.

You can either download the file, or you can link directly to the file in your HTML. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sketch</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.0/processing.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="application/processing">
            void setup(){
                size(200, 200);
            }

            void draw(){
                background(64);
                ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
            }
        </script>
        <canvas> </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Click here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/files/simple-processing-js-sketch.html) to view this file in your browser, or right-click to save it to use as a template. See [this](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/html/html) tutorial for instructions on working with .html files, including how to edit and view them.

Comment: I didn't know one could supply a custom type for the `type` attribute. What does that do, out of interest? Is that valid in HTML5?

Comment: @halfer It is valid HTML5, the browser doesn't do anything. `processing.js` reads it as text, parses it and executes it.